# Как удалить атрибут viewBox в IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Работаю с интерактивной `svg` картой, динамически вставляю `xml` разметку в `dom`, для масштабирования мешает `viewBox` у `svg`, перед вставкой регуляркой удаляю его, сейчас требования изменились и удалить `viewBox` нужно после вставки, любые другие атрибуты могу удалить, но не его.

js:

```
svg[0].removeAttribute('viewBox')
```

jquery:

```
svg.removeAttr('viewBox')
```

как ещё можно попробовать удалить?

Answer (score 1):

для ie помогло svg.attr('viewBox', ' ');